# Table loaded from csv in asciidoc have weird characters output

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I want to use asciidoc to produce a table. I use asciidocfx. I created 2 identical table, one load an external csv file while the other one is a simple table created in asciidoc. The problem is, the table from loaded csv file produce a � for these characters "..." . The table created using asciidoc doesnt produce that symbol for "..."

Here are the text

```
.CSV table
[format="csv",options="header"]
|===================================================
include::table.csv[]
|===================================================

.Asciidoc table
[options="header"]
|====
|Hello | World

| Hi
| Atlas...

| Hi
| Atlas..

| Hi
| Atlas.

|====
```

The content of table.csv

```
Hello ,World
Hi,Atlas...
Hi,Atlas..
Hi,Atlas.
```

snippet of html output.

```html
<div class="sectionbody">
<table class="tableblock frame-all grid-all spread data-line-14">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 50%;">
<col style="width: 50%;">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="tableblock halign-left valign-top">Hello</th>
<th class="tableblock halign-left valign-top">World</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Hi</p></td>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Atlas�</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Hi</p></td>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Atlas..</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Hi</p></td>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Atlas.</p></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="tableblock frame-all grid-all spread data-line-20">
<caption class="title">Table 1. My table</caption>
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 50%;">
<col style="width: 50%;">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="tableblock halign-left valign-top">Hello</th>
<th class="tableblock halign-left valign-top">World</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Hi</p></td>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Atlas…​</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Hi</p></td>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Atlas..</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Hi</p></td>
<td class="tableblock halign-left valign-top"><p class="tableblock">Atlas.</p></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your csv contains plain ASCII and not something like utf-8 chars ? "..." shoul an unique character coded in somthing else than ASCII. Try to open the CSV file with an hexadecimal editor to check if it's 3 dots or a multibyte character.

Comment: You were right. Excel export the csv file and create *that* character instead of "...". I have edited it in notepad. Hours wasted thinking that this is asciidoc issues. Thanks. By the way, could you post this as an answer so that I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"..." should be a single character and not 3 dots.
So you have a multibyte character suc as Utf-8 or other charset which is not ASCII.